# Getting around Column family ID mismatch Exception when I retry the query while creating schema on Cassandra using datastax java driver 4.10.0

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, datastax-java-driver

I have written a code that creates schema automatically, when my application comes up, using a schema file. Sometimes while executing a query I get a OperationTimedOutException  and I have written a retry mechanism for the same where if I get an OperationTimedOutException I retry the query.

Now, while using a multi host cluster, my application got an OperationTimedOutException, while creating a new table, and the code retried the query which successfully created the schema but after that I `org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Column family ID mismatch`

After doing a bit research I speculated that that although I got an OperationTimedOutException the request still got queued in Cassandra on one of the node and my retry code sent another request which might have landed on a different node and both these nodes created their version of table with different column family id and upon schema propagation encountered a mismatch.

Post this I stopped retrying my query in case of table creation and instead I keep getting the keyspace metadata and check whether the table has been created or not.

```
try{
execute(cql);
}
 catch (QueryOperationTimedOutExcetpion e) {
                        if (isKeyspaceCreationStatement) {
                            boolean createdServerSide = false;
                            while (!createdServerSide) {

                           ThreadUtils.sleep(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(5000));

                           KeyspaceMetadata keyspaceMetadata = getValueFromOptional(sessionToUse.getMetadata().getKeyspace(keyspace));
                           String cleanedKeyspaceExport = keyspaceMetadata.describeWithChildren(false).toLowerCase().replaceAll("\n", "");
}
```

This worked for a while and then I upgraded my datastax driver from `3.1.3` to `4.10.0` which removed OperationTimedOutException and introduced a DriverTimeoutException which is encountered if the client doesn't get a response from the server.
But post this upgrade I get stuck on the above mentioned code as the table never gets created. From what I understand is that DriverTimeoutException and OperationTimedOutException both gets returned when the client doesn't get a response from the server, but then why does the table never gets created. What should I do to ahead of this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The programmatic schema creation could be dangerous in the distributed system, such as Cassandra. What you see is so-called "Schema disagreement", and requires administrative intervention as described in [documentation](https://support.datastax.com/s/article/Handling-schema-disagreements-and-Schema-version-mismatch-detected-on-node-restart).  This happens because your code for creation/deletion of keyspaces/tables/... is sent to one node, and then it's propagated to other nodes - and in contrast to the "normal" operations, it doesn't obey consistency levels, etc. - it's completely different mechanism.

To avoid schema disagreement you need:

- if you send several DDL statements, they all needs to be sent to the same node to avoid possibility of sending next statement to another node that may not get updated schema yet.
- you need to wait until schema will be agreed by all nodes in the cluster - this should be done before sending the next DDL or performing data operations.  This is done by checking the `getExecutionInfo().isSchemaInAgreement()` on result of the DDL execution, or by calling `.checkSchemaAgreement()` on the session object (see [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.13/manual/core/metadata/schema/#schema-agreement))

Comment: I do check for an agreement post every DDL request made to the cluster. `ResultSet rs = execute(appStatement, sessionToUse);                     boolean inAgreement = rs.getExecutionInfo().isSchemaInAgreement();                     while (!inAgreement) {  Thread.sleep(5000)));                         inAgreement = clusterToUse.getMetadata().checkSchemaAgreement();                     } `